# Telegram bot authentication function

Tags: python, authentication, bots, telegram, aiogram

I am working on a Telegram bot (using aiogram package) and one of the requirements is to make user authentication. For example after /start command bot asks "Are you a client or an employee?" and employee has to send login and password to continue.

So, any suggestion for an elegant solution or maybe link to some repository with implementation would be appreciated.